# How intensive is Firebase.on? Can I have it set on thousands to millions of data?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Okay so I'm building a realtime app using Firebase with user profiles. I want user's profiles to update realtime on the view.

To do this, I have firebase.on('value') calls on each and everyone of the user's profiles then updates my views real time based on their values on the database.

My question is this: Is this okay when there are thousands or millions of potential data on the database?

Thanks.

Comment: Just wondering, wouldn't you imagine loading all profiles might be a bit much? Im not sure why a user would ever actually pull all million users profiles.

Comment: I want a real-time updates on searching for users. But I suppose that is overkill and not worth the hassle of setting on values on each and everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using the [child event listeners](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/retrieve-data#child-events) (child_added, child_changed, etc.), which trigger only during changes and return only the changed node.

[Value event listeners](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/retrieve-data#value_events) should only be used at very low levels, such as to watch a specific field of a specific child.